# Android call log query giving illegalargumentexception: column '_id' does not exist

Tags: java, android, calllog

I'm trying to get a list of the user's calls and I'm getting the illegalargumentexception: column '_id' does not exist.

This I find really weird because I did not create or have anything to do with the call Log table, I'm just trying to query it. Here's my code:

```
String[] strFields = {
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, 
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION
            };

String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC"; 

callCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            strFields,
            null,
            null,
            strOrder
            );



    // THE DESIRED COLUMNS TO BE BOUND
  String[] columns = new String[] { android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE, 
                                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION,
                                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
                                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER };
```

... and then I do some ListView/cursor adapter stuff.

So is there something I'm doing wrong here in this query? Are there any alternate solutions to accessing the call log?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a CursorAdapter then the callCursor  must include a column named "_id", otherwise the adapter will not work ([CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html))

You should add this String to your strFields array

```
android.provider.CallLog.Calls._ID
```

Then your CursorAdapter should work as expected